# Monitoring per-user resource usage with apache-mpm-itk

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring

So I have this Debian server running apache2 with mpm-itk, so that users have apache to run under their own uid for their own websites.

I would like to monitor resources usage (cpu, ram, ...) for each user (basically they just use apache and mysql). Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really! Your available configuration options are:

> AssignUserID: Takes two parameters, uid and gid (or really, user name
> and group name); specifies what uid and gid the vhost will run as
> (after parsing the request etc., of course). Note that if you do not
> assign a user ID, the default one from Apache will be used.
>
> MaxClientsVHost: A separate MaxClients for the vhost. This can be useful
> if, say, half of your vhosts depend on some NFS server (like on
> our setup); if the NFS server goes down, you do not want the children
> waiting forever on NFS to take the non-NFS-dependent hosts down. This
> can thus act as a safety measure, giving "server too busy" on the
> NFS-dependent vhosts while keeping the other ones happily running. (Of
> course, you could use it to simply keep one site from eating way too
> much resources, but there are probably better ways of doing that.)
>
> NiceValue: Lets you nice some requests down, to give them less CPU time.

More: http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/